# UE4 - How to play a sequence on level load

Tags: unreal-engine4

I was wondering how I can play a sequence when the level first starts in Unreal 4. I already have the sequence made, I just need it to play when the game begins, any help?

Comment: Add your sequence to Event:BeginPlay?

Answer (score -1):

In your level blueprint use the `Play` node on the sequence from `BeginPlay`